# Are Meta-2 Questions permitted on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

Are we allowed to ask questions about meta on meta? Or is meta only for discussing the main site? Thus, I am not sure if this question is acceptable here.

Answer (score 3):

You are free to ask any meta<sup>n</sup> question on the Philosophy Meta site, where `n <= ∞`. We may not always be able to provide an answer for you, but we should be able to direct you to a more appropriate place to ask your question if that's the case.